# Clarification on DBpedia Class and Namespace Differences - Beginner Inquiry

Tags: ontology, dbpedia, knowledge-graph, triples

I am currently working on a project involving DBpedia and, as a beginner, I am trying to get a clearer understanding of the various classes and namespaces used within DBpedia. Specifically, I'm struggling to differentiate between the following:

- http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/
- http://dbpedia.org/ontology/
- http://dbpedia.org/resource/
- http://dbpedia.org/property/
- http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/
- http://www.w3.org/1999/02/
- http://www.w3.org/2000/01/
- http://purl.org/dc/
- http://www.w3.org/2002/07/

I've come across these in my exploration of DBpedia, and I'd like to gain a better understanding of what each of these represents and contains. Could someone kindly provide insights into the purpose and typical content of these namespaces and classes within DBpedia?

Additionally, if there are any recommended resources or documentation that could help a beginner like me, I would greatly appreciate the guidance.

Thank you for your time.